# How to balance labeled datas and then carry out execution with a certain ratio?

Tags: neural-network, keras, tensorflow, class-imbalance, binary-classification

I'm building a binary classification model using a neural network, with python and the libraries tensorflow and keras.

For that I have an unequal amount of labeled data: Around 2'000'000 labeled with `1` and only 25'000 with `0`.

In order to train the model meaningfully, a balanced amount of data would be advantageous (as far as I understand).

However, I would also like to run the model with different ratios of the labeled data (3/1, 1/1, 1/3) in order to gain insights there too.

How is that possible? First of all to balance the imbalanced dataset, and then run the model with a given ratio (3/1, 1/1, 1/3) of labeled data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of subsampling the majority class, you can simply use class weights to give more importance to the minority class samples. For this, you can simply pass a dictionary with the weights to `model.fit`:

```
class_weight = {0: 1., 1: 50.}
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, nb_epoch=10, batch_size=255, class_weight=class_weight)
```

This way, instead of having different subsampling rations (75/25, 50/50, 25/75), you can train with different values of `class_weight` and evaluate their impact on the end result.

I suggest you check out the [official Tensorflow tutorial on imbalanced data](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/imbalanced_data), where they discuss this approach.

Comment: Thanks for this hint. I followed the instructions on TensorFlow tutorial about imbalanced datas. The `class_weights` are now set, but the output of the confusions matrix is very one-sided, 99% are in the confusions matrix in the positive/positive field, and 1% distributed on the other fields. Accuracy (0.98) and f1-score also. But it looks like something is wrong with the confusions matrix. How can I fix this?

Comment: Please, create a new question with the source code so that the community and I can help with that.